# Blank Screen for few secs on app launch on Android (No translucent theme avalaible)

Tags: android, launch

I want to get rid of the blank screen displayed few seconds after the app launch, but I only found the "Translucent Theme Solution" so far. But I cant apply this solution to my app, because the launcher activity is a log one, and with a button "disconnect" i want to be able to go back to it, without the translucent theme.
Is there anyway to do it?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is called a splash screen or splash activity. You can create your own splash. There are some tutorials about this on YouTube

Comment: I guess, You forgot to add UI part in your Splash Screen's layout file.

Comment: You need to "load" something that is quick like a _placeholder_ image or a simple webview which is loaded from the device. Then, in the background load your _slower to load_ app stuff. Once that has loaded, then replace your placeholder graphic / webview.